# Expandable datatable in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm showing a list of objects to my users, I would like them to have a quick view on the values of 5 fields of this object. For this purpose I feel like a datatable is the best component to use.
But I would also like them to be able to click on a specific row and get more information on that specific record (in the form of a card for example).

[image]

I couldn't find any examples like that using lightning web component. I found this kind of example using aura : [Is there a way to insert a <div> right below a datatable row?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245805/is-there-a-way-to-insert-a-div-right-below-a-datatable-row) but from my understanding, I cannot use aura component in LWC.

Any solution ? Or suggestion of what I should look into to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is doable if you add a row action (column with dropdown of possible action) to data table and  create it as a link or button which opens Modal (having card if you will) showing your required details from that Row. In you controller have a handler for onrowaction={handleRowActions} within the lightning-datatable>

Hope this helps.